# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?

Tags: python, http, url

I'm trying to fetch some data off of internet.

So on the main page, there are multiple posts, and for each post, there is an URL that I need to go into. The first for loop is working fine as it goes through each post on the main page, fetching some data.

When I want the code to get into individual URL of each post, it stops working. Error message I get is:

> requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?

> Process finished with exit code 1

```
#import get to call a get request on the site
from requests import get
from warnings import warn

#get the first page of the east bay housing prices
response = get('https://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/cto?purveyor-input=all&hasPic=1') #get rid of those lame-o's that post a housing option without a pic using their filter

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

#get the macro-container for the housing posts
posts = html_soup.find_all('li', class_= 'result-row')
print(type(posts)) #to double check that I got a ResultSet
print(len(posts)) #to double check I got 120 (elements/page)

for elem in posts:

    price = elem.find('span', class_= 'result-price')
    # location = elem.find('span', class_= 'result-hood')
    url = elem.find('a', class_= 'result-image gallery')
    title = elem.find('a', class_= 'result-title hdrlnk')
    # print(location.text.strip())
    print(title.text.strip())
    print(price.text.strip())
    print(url['href'])


for each_sing_page in url:


    response2 = get(each_sing_page)
    single_soup = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'html.parser')
```

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Whats the value of `each_sing_page`?

Comment: Value of "each_sing_page" is text, like https://......
I got it extracted from HTML script, so it should be text

Comment: I actually just checked the type of URL by going print(type(URL)), it says <class 'str'>. Maybe that's why it didn't compile. But when I go print(url), it actually outputs the correct URL for me like https://.....

Comment: have you tried a simple example like `print(requests.get("https://google.co.uk"))` to see if that works. then try the same with your example URL

Comment: Sorry i just realised you pasted your full code, but the value of `each_sing_page` is more than just the URL. You need to recheck your code structure and data